# can't take X-Total-Count from response header

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, postman, react-query

when I check the request through the X-Total-Count network there is but when I output the answer to the console there is nothing I don't understand why this is

[image]

through the Postman application, I also checked the output

[image]

but when I want to display all this on the console, I get undefined why ????

[image]

My Code:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useGeneralAPIQuery } from "../../hooks/queries";
import { quickSearchDTO } from "../../types/utils";
import axios from "axios";

const Button = () => {
    const quickSearchQuery = useGeneralAPIQuery<quickSearchDTO[]>("/group", { size: 8 });
    console.log("quickSearchQuery", quickSearchQuery.data)

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('http://192.168.8.126:8051/cl-api-react/group?size=8')
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log("header", response.headers);
            });
    }, [])
    
    return (
        <div>
            
        </div>
    );
};
export default Button;
```

console

[image]

no X-Total-Count in the console I tried everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers can only access some response headers by default when it comes to CORS request, the default response headers are the ones listed below:

1. Cache-Control
2. Content-Language
3. Content-Type
4. Expires
5. Last-Modified
6. Pragma

The CORS spec requires the server to give permissions explicitly for the client side app to read headers other then the default ones.

So, in order to solve that issue you need to set the Access-Control-Expose-Headers header on your server so it will be allowed to be read on your client app.

You can read more about this issue here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers

Answer (score 0):

Try something likes this

```js
useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('http://192.168.8.126:8051/cl-api-react/group?size=8')
        .then(res => {
            console.log("header", res.headers);
        });
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

CORS only allows some headers by default. To allow the desired header you have to use `Access-Control-Expose-Headers`

Here is an example of how you can use it:

```
res.set('X-Total-Count',totalDocs);
res.set('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'X-Total-Count');
```